# CakePHP: how work the cache groups?

Tags: cakephp, caching, cakephp-2.3

I'm trying to use the cache groups, but the [examples in the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/caching.html#using-groups) are not very clear for me.

This is my *bootstrap*:

```
Cache::config('default', array(
    'engine' => $engine,
    'duration' => $duration,
    'prefix' => $prefix,
    'groups' => array('page', 'photo', 'post')
));
```

We suppose that I have the model, including articles, pages, photos, etc., and in the various actions the data is written to the cache.

For example, *PagesController*:

```
public function index() {
    $pages = Cache::read($cache = 'pages_index');

    if(empty($pages)) {
        $pages = $this->Page->find('all');
        Cache::write($cache, $pages);
    }

    $this->set(array(
        'pages'             => $pages
    ));
}
```

This creates the file

```
tmp/cache/pages_index
```

The cache is working correctly, the next request will use the cache. 
Others actions write the data for the *Page* model page.

Again *PagesController*:

```
public function view($slug = NULL) {
    $page = Cache::read($cache = sprintf('pages_view_%s', $slug));

    //If the data are not available from the cache
    if(empty($page)) {
        $page = $this->Page->find('first', array(
            'conditions'    => array('slug' => $slug)
        ));

        if(empty($page))
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid page'));

        Cache::write($cache, $page);
    }

    $this->set(array(
        'page'              => $page
    ));
}
```

This also works correctly.

Now I wish that editing a page being deleted from the cache all the data about pages. The same should happen for the other models (posts, photos, etc).

So, in my *Page* model:

```
public function afterSave($created, $options = array()) {
    Cache::clearGroup('pages');
}
```

But this does not work: no files are deleted from the cache.

Where am I doing wrong? What I do not understand?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because Your group name is 'page', not 'pages'.